# Implementing jquery ajax in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am new to jquery and have been following this guide on how to create instant search via jquery:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AqM9U3mi9A&t=303s

I a trying to implement this on my wordpress site, but apparently things work differently when it comes to a wordpress site.

I am kind of looking for a "how to"-guide in basic steps on how to implement instant search on a wordpress site :)

Currently when I try to search(with the setup from the video), i get the following error in the browser console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Hope that someone can help :)

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress ajax is user through the hook [wp_ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) and wp_ajax_npriv
[Link to docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Since the latest WordPress version you could ajax to the [wp rest API](http://v2.wp-api.org/) endpoints.

jQuery is included in WordPress, but you can't use $ directly. Either use "jQuery" instead of "$" or wrap the function like this:

```
(function($) {

  // $ Works inside this function

})( jQuery );
```

If you want to add live search to your site, there are a [few plugins in the repo that do that](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=live%20search).